# Connecting to Docker containers created using docker-machine from a different machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have created some containers using `docker-machine` and they are up and running on digital ocean.

Now I want to connect to those containers from a different machine. I have used [`machine-share`](https://github.com/bhurlow/machine-share)'s export and import on the new machine and can see that I now have the relevant config's and keys for the containers in `$HOME/.docker/machine/machines/`

However when I run `docker-machine ls` I can an empty list, how do I complete the final step and actually connect to the running containers from the second machine?

I also tried `docker-machine env <container-name>` but it returns `Docker machine "<container-name>" does not exist.`

Comment: You should be able to directly connect to the published ports on the remote host; you don't need Docker Machine or any other Docker-related tooling for this.  Can you give a more specific example of the container you're running, its port-related options, and the connection errors you're getting?

Comment: Do you mean that you're running docker-machine on the digital-ocean instances? If so, you're (probably) doing the wrong thing. Docker-machine is an old way to run containers on windows laptops. On digital-ocean you should just stand up an ubuntu instance and install docker directly on the OS, and run your containers there, exposing their ports using the -p option.

Comment: should have clarified, the machine I'm importing to will be the "orchestration" node where different team members can ssh in and manage containers on many different droplets using docker-machine (the problem we were facing was a team member needs to restart a container but someone else owned the docker-machine on their laptop)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that Docker/Docker-Machine installed by Snaps on Ubuntu did not have the required permissions to read the relevant certificates installed by `machine-import`.

To solve this you can either grant snaps the correct permissions to read from `.docker/machine/**` or install docker and docker-machine directly. I tried the latter and now the containers show up correctly when I run `docker-machine ls`